# Push Notification not receiving on several Devices - only get Push on one Device

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, push, apple-push-notifications

i have a little problem with my PHP Code.
I did not get it to work, that the message i sent, will receive on all Devices witch are saved in my Database.

The Push App on the Device registers automatically the deviceToken in my MySQL Database. That is all working fine.

The big problem is, that i get the Push Message only to the FIRST Device from the Database. The other Device don't receive any message.

Here my code:

```
<?php

require_once('konfiguration.php');

$sql = "SELECT deviceToken FROM DeviceTokens";
$dbquery = mysql_query($sql);

// check checkboxes
$message = $_POST['alert'];
$badge = $_POST['badge'];
$sound = $_POST['sound'];
// Construct the notification payload
$body = array();
// anti-error variable
$nothing = true; 
// get user input
if ($message) { $alert=$_POST['message']; $nothing = false;
$body['aps']['alert'] = $alert; }
if ($badge) { $nothing = false;
if($_POST['number']) $number=(int)$_POST['number'];
else $number=1;
$body['aps']['badge'] = $number; }
if ($sound) { $nothing = false;
$body['aps']['sound'] = 'beep.wav'; }
// if input not correct, scream
if ($nothing || ($message && $alert=="")) { echo "Falscher Input!"; exit(); }
//make new stream context
$ctx = stream_context_create();
// set parameters
$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'w3workProd.pem');
//stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'nils');

$socketClient = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $error,      
$errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

$payload = json_encode($body);

print "sending message :" . $payload . "\n";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($dbquery)) {
$message = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken))   
.chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
$deviceToken = str_replace(' ', '', $row['deviceToken']);
$message = pack('CnH*', 0, 32, $deviceToken);
$message = $message . pack('n', strlen($payload));
$message = $message . $payload;

fwrite($socketClient, $message);
echo ($row['deviceToken']);
}

fclose($socketClient);
exit();
?>
```

Would be nice if you can help.
Why is it working with one Device...and not with the others...

Comment: Is that only device that receives message the one that sent it?

Comment: Only the Device gets the Push, witch deviceToken is the first one in the Databse (depending on ID Number). The others dont get any message.

I sent the messages via a little Interface from a html Website. All is working fine, but only the first Token is taken for the messages. The others one are not receiving anything

Comment: Remove all `exit` and try then. Maybe one of them exits script (if used in loop).

Comment: I removed the "exit();" but still not working...
Push Message is receiving on first Device, other 2 Device are not receiving a message.

Comment: Open and close socket in loop. This is my final hope to guess why your script does not do what's expected.

Comment: ok, how will i do that? where to put the loop in?

Comment: Put`$socketClient = `stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $error,      
$errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);` and `f_close($socketClient);` in while loop.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

> STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT

?